# Laguerre's method to obtain poly roots

Tags: matlab

I have to write using Laguerre's method a piece of code to find real and complex roots of poly: 
f(x)=a4x4+a3x3+a2x2+a1x+a0 , [a4 a3 a2 a1 a0]=[-2 5 5 2 1]
I got something:

---

```
function y = laguerre (x,coef)
tol = 10^(-10);
%polynomial order
n = length(coef);
i = 0;
while (abs(polyval(coef,x)) > tol)
i = i + 1
x
polyval(coef,x)
%second derivative
a=polyval(polyder(polyder(coef)), x);
%first derivative
b=polyval(polyder(coef), x);
%polynomial value
c=polyval(coef, x);
%square root
r = sqrt((n-1)*[(n-1)*b^2-n*a*c]);
d1 = b + r;
d2 = b - r;
%highest abs value denominator chosen
if (abs(d1) > abs(d2))
    d = d1;
else
    d = d2;
end
%next iteration value obtained
z = n*c/d;
x = x - z;
end
i = i + 1
x
polyval(coef,x)
y = x;
return
end
```

and I want to draw and/ or obtain my roots:

```
coef = [-2 5 5 2 1];
fh = @poly;
%diary on
%plot of the function
figure(1);
fplot(fh, [-500 500]);
hold on;
figure(2);
fplot(fh, [-1.5 3]);
hold on;
%roots obtained using MM2
%z1(1) = MM2(-500,coef);
%z1(2) = MM2(500,coef);
%z1(3) = MM2(1 + i, coef);
%z1(4) = MM2(0 - 2i, coef);
%roots obtained using Laguerre's 
%z2(1) = laguerre(-500,coef);
z2(2) = laguerre(500,coef);
%z2(3) = laguerre(1 + i, coef);
%z2(4) = laguerre(0 - 2i, coef);
%additional points on plot
p = [z1(1) z2(2)];
plot(p,[0 0],'r*');
legend('function','zeros');
hold off;
figure(1);
plot(p,[0 0],'r*');
plot([-500 500],[0 0], 'b*');
legend('function','zeros','START points');
diary off;
hold off;
```

As you see, some part of code is commented because I really don't know how to move on. I got many warnings. I got one error in 1st part of the code. I am looking for some tips or direction what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly well, you should get the roots

```
x=-500     =>  x=-0.6694729, p(x)=-8.882D-16 in 9 steps 
x= 500     =>  x=3.3489712, p(x)=1.621D-14 in 8 steps  
x=1 + i    =>  x=-0.0897491+i*0.4636332, p(x)=i*8.327D-17 in 4 steps  
x=0 - 2i   =>  x=-0.0897491-i*0.4636332, p(x)=i*5.551D-17 in 4 steps
```

To illustrate the bigger picture, the iteration map for the Laguerre method with initial values in `[-4,4]+[-4,4]*i` looks like

[image: Laguerre fractal]

Every color shade represents one step. There is nothing nefarious in this polynomial preventing convergence of the method.

To compare with, the Halley iteration map is

[image: Halley fractal]

and the Newton fractal

[image: Newton fractal]